# Azure AKS node reboot alert

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-vm-scale-set

Wonder if I can have an alert for the Azure AKS when a node reboot?

What have already tried:
Used KubeEvents and the reason reboot, is there another way?
Couldn't find any docs about that on the azure website.

Answer (score 0):

If I good understand your question, the solution should be described in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-updates-kured). You can used `Kured` tool  to [monitor and review reboot process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/node-updates-kured#monitor-and-review-reboot-process).

See also [this good article](https://denniszielke.medium.com/dashboard-and-notifications-on-aks-for-required-worker-nodes-reboots-c883d08e9404).

Comment: Want to have the alert when the node get rebooted not before that.

Comment: Please, read the attached docs. At the bottom of the article you can find a paragraph Getting notifications for pending reboots.

Comment: The alert i want is not for pending reboots, but to get an alert when the reboot happen

Comment: Your question was very imprecise. Please clarify it. If you want to have an alert after the reboot your node you can use [kernel monitor](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/monitor-node-health/#kernel-monitor) and create your own rule according to this documentation.